# Create thread to optimise Android GridView performance

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-gridview

I am new to Android development
I am trying to create a thread to take on the work of scrolling through a gridview component in an application. 
The gridview consists of 9 images that the user can scroll through to select the appropriate option. This, however, lags badly and the logcat throws the error "Skipped 101 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread"

I have decided to create a thread to assist the main thread, but I am unsure of how to do this.

I have added some of my code below:

**ImageAdapter.java**

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         Thread gridThread = new Thread(ImageAdapter.this);
         gridThread.setDaemon(true);
         gridThread.start();

         ImageView imageView;
         if (convertView == null) {

             imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
             imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(585, 585));
             imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
             imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
         } else {
             imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
     }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {

            if (position == 0) {

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "You have selected an invalid option. Please select a Province from the list on screen",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: All the UI updates are performed in the main thread (UI thread) including scrolling. Your code should work just fine without any additional threads so i suggest removing the gridThread. Unless your images are huge, there should be no performance impact on scrolling.

Comment: What type are your `mThumbIds`? (`Bitmap`, path `String`, etc.) ?

Comment: It is JPEG actually. I think that perhaps the images are too big. What would be an appropriate file size for images used in an android application? My current ones are between 22kb and 130kb.